# Unable to access first data item in JSON Array

Tags: arrays, json

I'm having trouble pulling a piece of data from a JSON array. I believe I've tried every answer from similar posts here but I'm missing something. I've imported the org.JSON library. Here is my JSON text:

```
{
  "symbol":"AAPL",
  "earnings":[
  {
    "actualEPS":2.34,
    "consensusEPS":2.17,
    "estimatedEPS":2.17,
    "announceTime":"AMC",
    "numberOfEstimates":10,
    "EPSSurpriseDollar":0.17,
    "EPSReportDate":"2018-07-31",
    "fiscalPeriod":"Q3 2018",
    "fiscalEndDate":"2018-06-30",
    "yearAgo":1.67,
    "yearAgoChangePercent":0.40119760479041916,
    "estimatedChangePercent":0.29        940119760479045,
    "symbolId":11
  },
  {
    "actualEPS":2.73,
    "consensusEPS":2.69,
    ...
    ...
  }
]
```

I'm trying to read the first instance of "actualEPS", there are a total of four in the array. My code currently looks like this:

```
    String jsonIn = sb.toString();
    JSONArray earningsArray = new JSONArray(jsonIn);
    double eps = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < earningsArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jObject = earningsArray.getJSONObject(i);
         eps = jObject.getDouble("actualEPS");
    } // end for loop

    System.out.println("This is the first instance of EPS: " + eps);
```

The StringBuilder (sb) in the first line is my JSON and prints out correctly in the console just ahead of this block.

The stack trace shows the error in this line:

```
    JSONArray earningsArray = new JSONArray(jsonIn);
```

The error I'm getting is
"A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]"

I've never used JSON prior to now and am not sure what my error is exactly. I tried shortening the String going into the array to begin with just the array opening bracket but that didn't work either. I feel like I'm missing something simple. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You're passing a JSON Object, not a JSON Array. The standard is not that complicated, have a look at http://www.json.org/

Comment: So the entire data field is an object. I need to pass the array inside of it to my array initialization statement, correct? Do I parse the array out by creating an object and then calling .getArray on the object? If so, do I call it by name "earnings"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand there are two types of datastructure in a JSON.

1. first is Object which always starts with '{' and ends with '}'
2. second is Array which always starts with '[' and ends with ']'

JsonArray is nothing but an array of JsonObject means a json array will always look like

```
"jsonarray":[
    {
    //json object
    },
    {
    // json object
    }
]
```

hope now you understand how json works

now come to your json

```
{  // jsonObjectParent Starts
  "symbol":"AAPL",
  "earnings":[  // jsonArray Starts
     { //jsonObject1 Starts
       "actualEPS":2.34,
       "consensusEPS":2.17,
       "estimatedEPS":2.17,
       "announceTime":"AMC",
       "numberOfEstimates":10,
       "EPSSurpriseDollar":0.17,
       "EPSReportDate":"2018-07-31",
       "fiscalPeriod":"Q3 2018",
       "fiscalEndDate":"2018-06-30",
       "yearAgo":1.67,
       "yearAgoChangePercent":0.40119760479041916,
       "estimatedChangePercent":0.29        940119760479045,
       "symbolId":11
     },  // jsonOject1 Ends
     { //jsonObject2
       "actualEPS":2.73,
       "consensusEPS":2.69,
       ...
       ...
     }
   ]   //jsonArray Ends
 }    //jsonObjectParent Ends
```

So here if you want to parse this json you have to first parse it in a jsonObject as you seen above

```
JsonObject jsonObjectParent = new JsonObject(jsonIn);
// here jsonobject contains json array so etract it like this
JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObjectParent.getJsonArray("earnings");
//now you can access the values here
JsonObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJsonObject(0); // here 0 means first jsonObject in array if you want all you can make a loop here
string actualEps = jsonObject1.getDouble("actualEPS");
```

Hope now you understands the concept of how JSON Works

please let me know is this solution worked

Comment: This did it, thank you. I thought I had tried this before but I must have missed something.

Answer (score 0):

@Driver8, the JSON `earninsArray` is a single JSON object and not an array of JSON objects. Your basic idea here is alright everywhere excpet for just that line. Instead of instantiating a JSON array, instantiate a **JSON OBJECT**.

Should be something like this:

```
String jsonIn = sb.toString();
JSONObject earningsObject = new JSONObject(jsonIn);
JSONArray earningsArray = earningsObject.getJSONArray("earnings");
double eps = new double(earningsArray.length());

for (int i = 0; i < earningsArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject j1 = earningsArray.getJSONObject(i);
    eps[i] = j1.getDouble("actualEPS");
}
```

All the values of `actualEPS` will be stored as per their order in the array declared to store the EPS values.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray data = json.optJSONArray("earnings");

for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {

   JSONObject jsonObject1 = data.getJSONObject(i);

   Double actualEPS = jsonObject1.getDouble("actualEPS");
   Double consensusEPS = jsonObject1.getDouble("consensusEPS");
   Double estimatedEPS= jsonObject1.getDouble("estimatedEPS");
   String announceTime = jsonObject1.getString("announceTime");
   int numberOfEstimates = jsonObject1.getInt("numberOfEstimates");
   Double EPSSurpriseDollar= jsonObject1.getDouble("EPSSurpriseDollar");
   String EPSReportDate= jsonObject1.getString("EPSReportDate");
   String fiscalPeriod= jsonObject1.getString("fiscalPeriod");
   String fiscalEndDate= jsonObject1.getString("fiscalEndDate");
   Double yearAgo= jsonObject1.getDouble("yearAgo");
   Double yearAgoChangePercent= jsonObject1.getDouble("yearAgoChangePercent");
   Double estimatedChangePercent = jsonObject1.getDouble("estimatedChangePercent");
   int symbolId = jsonObject1.getInt("symbolId");
}
```